# Common elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have 2 list-of-lists

```
a = [(468, 15), (336, 280), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150), (180, 150)]
b = [(200, 200), (200, 90), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150)]
```

I want to find elements that are the same between both lists and eliminate them.
`b[0]` is NOT present in `a`, only one of `b[1]` & `b[2]` is present in `a`, `b[3]` and `b[4]` are BOTH present in `a`.

I need the maximum occurrence in each list to be sent to another list (the others are counted as repeats) i.e. I need this to be my output

```
combined = [(468, 15), (336, 280), (200, 200), (200, 90), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150), (180, 150)]
```

Note: I have gone through solutions but they convert these lists into "sets" which eliminates the 'repeat' occurrences.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit: Explanation of how the output was made

`(468, 15)` occurs 1 time in a.
`(336, 280)` occurs 1 time in a.
`(200, 200)` occurs 1 time in b.
`(200, 90)` occurs 1 time in a, 2 times in b.
`(180, 150)` occurs 3 times in a, 2 times in b.

The output is the max occurrence between both lists i.e.

`(468, 15)` once.
`(336, 280)` once.
`(200, 200)` once.
`(200, 90)` twice.
`(180, 150)` thrice.

Making the list as given in `combined`

Comment: does order of items matter?

Comment: @RustamGarayev No they don't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since order does not matter, you can put all items into a set, and add the max occurrences of each item:

```
a = [(468, 15), (336, 280), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150), (180, 150)]
b = [(200, 200), (200, 90), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150)]

res = [each for each in set(a + b) for i in range(max(a.count(each), b.count(each)))]
```

`res` would look like this:

```
[(180, 150), (180, 150), (180, 150), (200, 200), (468, 15), (336, 280), (200, 90), (200, 90)]
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you @Rustam Garayev! Could you tell me how this comprehension does what it does?

Comment: @Nilima First for loop looks for each unique element in the combination of 2 lists, and the second loop determines how many times each element should be added to the final list

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using `collections.Counter`. At least to my eyes this corresponds the best to how I think about the problem:

```
from collections import Counter

ca = Counter(a)
cb = Counter(b)

result = [
    element  # every element
    for element in ca | cb  # that is in either input
    for _ in range(max(ca[element], cb[element]))  # the larger amount of times it occurs
]
```

This will of course only work when your elements are hashable (= can be keys in a dictionary, or elements in a set).

Comment: "not the fastest" Certainly faster than calling `count` for each individual element. For flattening, you could also use `[x for x in ca | cb for _ in range(max(ca[x], cb[x]))]`

Comment: @tobias_k Nice! For some reason, I thought it would probably look clunkier if I unrolled it manually, but thanks to `Counter.__missing__` composing well with `max()`, that doesn't turn out to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
a = [(468, 15), (336, 280), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150), (180, 150)]
b = [(200, 200), (200, 90), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150)]


[[d] * max(a.count(d), b.count(d)) for d in set(a+b)]
```

Comment: @Nilima, this is shortest answer for you :)))

Comment: Yes :) This is extremely elegant! I wish I could give 2 green ticks here.

Answer (score 0):

The above can be resolved by adding the lists and removing the duplicates.

example as below:

```
a = [(468, 15), (336, 280), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150), (180, 150)]
b = [(200, 200), (200, 90), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150)]
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(a+b))
print(mylist)
```

Comment: It returns ```[(468, 15), (336, 280), (200, 90), (180, 150), (200, 200)]``` but OP asked the output should be ```[(468, 15), (336, 280), (200, 200), (200, 90), (200, 90), (180, 150), (180, 150), (180, 150)]```

Comment: @RMR I do not want to use dict or set because they reduce my lists - which is something that I do not want